# C# Accessing non-interfaced methods of an object in an interface array

Tags: c#, arrays, types, interface

I have an Array of an interface named iBlocks which contains objects of more than a single class(that all implement the iBlocks interface). I'm wondering if it is possible, or how else to handle the situation in which i need to call methods not covered by the interface for all objects of a certain class within this array. 
For example:

```
iBlocks = new iBlocks[1];
iBlocks[0] = new greenBlock();
iBlocks[1] = new yellowBlock();

foreach (greenBlock in iBlocks)
{
   greenBlock.doStuff()
}
```

Where doStuff() is a method not defined in the interface, as it has no use in the yellowBlock class. The actual interface works brilliantly as greenBlock and yellowBlock have tons of common features. However, there are special aspects of each class i would like to still access without creating an entirely separate array for each object type.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are needing to invoke methods of your objects that would expose  more than your interface, then perhaps you need to rethink the way those objects interact with this particular class i.e The design might be tightly coupled even with the interface.

Comment: It might help to explain the purpose you had for the interface and the relationships between the classes. Then maybe we can find a more flexible design that will allow you to avoid have to hard cast objects or check types (eeewwwwww).

Comment: The interface acts as a collection of many types of blocks present in one instance of an area class. The interface handles basic commands like getting, setting co-ordinates, updating(for animation), and initiating drawing of the blocks. I am early in the project and there is expected to be many, many more types of blocks. Each block will need to implement this same interface but will of course have unique operations(otherwise why make more classes?) that the Area class will need to call when necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `as` operator.

```
foreach (var block in iBlocks)
{
    var green = block as greenBlock;
    if (green != null)
         green.doStuff()
}
```

Or in LINQ

```
foreach (var green in iBlocks.OfType<greenBlock>())
{
    green.doStuff()
}
```

Comment: OfType was exactly what i was looking for. Comments suggest that type checking is messy, although i see no problem with it!